Protecting the formula, move it to another cell and keep output in original cell?
I need to approach this a different way. My sheet has date fields for selecting a range of dates (A2 and B2). This works exactly as I need, I can pull a list of trips for any range of dates in the list of field trips.
My problem is that the script to duplicate trips overwrites all the data rows with the new data, so my formula is lost. I need the formula to stay for the next time I need to pull a trip schedule.
I think the solution is to move the formula to a different row. The script skips the first three rows. How can I move the formula into, let's say D1, but have the formula output to cell A4?
Here is my spreadsheet. Look at the sheet called Trip Schedule. I need the date pickers (cell A2 and B2) to choose the selection of trips (this already works), then I run the duplicate trips script, then take that list of results and build a trip schedule document.
function duplicateTrips() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Trip Schedule")
  var data = sheet.getRange(4,1,sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var newData = [];
  for(var n in data){
    newData.push(data[n]);
    if(!Number(data[n][2])){continue};// if column 3 is not a number then do nothing
    for(var c=1 ; c < Number(data[n][2]) ; c++){ // start from 1 instead of 0 because we     have already 1 copy
      newData.push(data[n]);//store values
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange(4,1,newData.length,newData[0].length).setValues(newData);// write new data to sheet, overwriting old data
}


Would you please edit the question to provide sample data as well as an example of the expected outcome.

I re-worked my question and changed the scope of what I was asking. Please see my updated question. Thanks!

This var data = sheet.getRange(4,1,sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(); should be var data = sheet.getRange(4,1,sheet.getLastRow()-3, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();

You should not be using for(var n in data) try data.forEach((row,index) =>) data[n][2]would berow[2]`

Related question: Repeat whole row N times based on column value in Google Sheets

You want the basic data AND the replicated lines AND sorted by trip date (AND keep your original formula). May I suggest that you are, as they say, trying to "have you cake and eat it". IMHO, I don't think that this is possible. I see two options; 1) replace the existing formula with one that delivers ALL the necessary data or 2) use a script to generate the data in the first instance.

Consider this answer executed by a script:

the script is triggered by onEdit
createTrips() - builds the Trip Schedule sheet

clears the existing Trip Schedule
Values for the Start and End dates are obtained and converted to numbers (of milliseconds) using valueOf
a temporary Array (tripArray) is used to build the contents of the Trip Schedule
Loop though the "Trip Date" column of the "Data" sheet testing for dates within the Start and End dates.
then push as many rows of data as the value in the "Busses" column
updates the Trip Schedule by setValues(tripArray)




function onEdit(e) {

  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) // DEBUG

  var editedValue=e.value
  var editedSheet = e.range.getSheet().getName()
  var editedRow = e.range.rowStart
  var editedCol = e.range.columnStart
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: edited value = "+editedValue+", edited sheet = "+editedSheet+", edited row = "+editedRow+", edited Column = "+editedCol)

  var sheet2Watch = "Trip SchedulebyScript"
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: edited sheet = "+editedSheet+", sheet to watch = "+sheet2Watch+", edited value = "+editedValue)

  // test for sheet and edited value
  if (editedSheet != sheet2Watch || editedValue != "TRUE") {
    // no match, do nothing
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: no match, do nothing")
    return
  }
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: match = build trip schedule")
  createTrips()
}
function createTrips() {

  var tripSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Trip SchedulebyScript")
  
  // clear existing data from tripSheet
  var clearTripRange = tripSheet.getRange(4,1,tripSheet.getLastRow()+1,tripSheet.getLastColumn()).clear({contentsOnly: true});
  Logger.log("DEBUG: cleared existing data")

  // get the user variables
  var startDate = tripSheet.getRange("A1").getValue()
  var endDate = tripSheet.getRange("B1").getValue()
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: Start date = "+startDate+"\nEnd date = "+endDate)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: value of Start date = "+startDate.valueOf())

  // get the data
  var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data")
  var data = dataSheet.getDataRange().getValues()

  // convert the date column of the data into a 1d array for analysis
  var dates = data.map(function(e){return e[0]})
  // Logger.log(dates) // DEBUG

  // create a temporary Array to hold the data rows
  var tripArray = new Array



  // loop through dates to find matches of the Start and End dates
  for (var i=0;i<dates.length;i++){
    if ((dates[i].valueOf() >= startDate.valueOf()) && (dates[i].valueOf() <= endDate.valueOf())){
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: row "+(i+1)" is a match: "+startDate+"="+dates[i])

      // duplicate the rows as required
      for (var b=0;b<data[i][2];b++ ){
        tripArray.push(data[i])
      }
    }
  }
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: number of trip rows = "+tripArray.length+", number of trip columns = "+tripArray[0].length)

  // paste triparray into the spreadsheet
  tripSheet.getRange(4,1,tripArray.length,tripArray[0].length).setValues(tripArray)
  Logger.log("DEBUG: updated Trip Schedule sheet")

}


SAMPLE - Checkbox


ADDENDUM - "Delete" rows instead of "clear" rows
The OP asks how to "delete the rows of data rather than "clear" them. The process is slightly more complicated.
The "sheet" method deleteRows(rowPosition, howMany) replaces the "range" method clear(options). This should be straightforward but a couple of issues were noted during testing.

If the checkbox is checked with no data on the sheet, then the script failed because of a inadequate value of "howMany".

A test to check the number of rows of data was added and, if the value was "zero" then a default value of "1" is used.


Continuous deletion of rows raises the possibility that the data, when inserted, will be formatted according the header row - that is, all bold.

This is resolved by adding .setFontWeight("normal") to the line that updates the data. It ensures that all the data is formatted without bolding.




In function createTrips():
Remove these lines
// clear existing data from tripSheet
  var clearTripRange = tripSheet.getRange(4,1,tripSheet.getLastRow()+1,tripSheet.getLastColumn()).clear({contentsOnly: true});
  Logger.log("DEBUG: cleared existing data")


Substitute these lines
// delete existing rows of data from tripSheet
  // get the number of rows of data - include a test for no rows
  var numOfRowsData = +tripSheet.getLastRow()-4+1
  if (numOfRowsData <1 ){
    numOfRowsData = 1
  }
  Logger.log("last row = "+tripSheet.getLastRow()+", number of rows = "+numOfRowsData+", columns = "+tripSheet.getLastColumn())
  // delete the rows
  tripSheet.deleteRows(4, numOfRowsData)
  Logger.log("DEBUG: deleted the rows")


Amend this line
tripSheet.getRange(4,1,tripArray.length,tripArray[0].length).setValues(tripArray).setFontWeight("normal");



I'm sorry I missed this reply. I'm working on it now.

OH MY JEBUS!! I renamed my sheet... DUH.... I need to learn to try all the things before I start commenting. It works perfectly! I'm going to delete the other comments.

How to change it to delete the rows, not just clear them? Clearing the rows leaves behind the merged cells.  After the script runs, I do some editing. Ultimately I need it to be arranged like the Print this Trip Schedule sheet.

How to change it to delete the rows, not just clear them? I have added an "addendum" that explains how to do this. So far as Ultimately I need it to be arranged like the Print this Trip Schedule sheet - this has been added after both answers were submitted. You should raise a new question if you are unable to resolve it.

Ultimately I need it to be arranged like the Print this Trip Schedule sheet. OK, curiosity got the better of me. But it is NOT a trivial piece of code; I (a bumbling hacker) took about 5 hours to complete. It IS outside the scope of this question, but let me know if you need help.

Thank you for all the time you have spend on this! It's working exactly as I need.          Your last comment has me a bit confused. I know the final arrangement on the Print This Trip Schedule sheet is outside of the scope of my initial question. Did you actually work on that too?

You have a FILTER generating data based on given date parameters. You want to replicate n rows of the filtered data for each row where the value in a given column ("Buses") is greater than 1.
Consider this approach based on the approach used by @TheMaster in Repeat whole row N times based on column value in Google Sheets.
This answer does not use a script, but does use "helper" columns.
Helper Query

Copy the header row (row#3) into range "L3:T3"
Enter "Repeat" in cell U3
Enter this QUERY formula into cell L4

=query({Data!A2:I},"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,(Col3+0) where Col1 is not null and Col1 >= date '"&TEXT(A1,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"'  and Col1 <= date '"&TEXT(B1, "yyyy-MM-dd")&"'  label (Col3+0) ''")
This is a substitute for the existing FILTER function, except that duplicates the "Buses" column at the end of the output (and makes it accessible for the replication formula).




Replication formula

Enter this formula in Cell A3

=REDUCE(L3:T3,U4:INDEX(U3:U,COUNTA(U3:U)),
  LAMBDA(a,c,
    LAMBDA(row,
      {
        a;
        IF(c > 1,
          REDUCE(row,SEQUENCE(c-1),LAMBDA(a_,c_,{a_;row})),
          row
        )
      }
    )(OFFSET(c,0,-9,1,9))
  )
)


SAMPLE - Data replication


SAMPLE - Query Output

